# How to set selected some index of TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 10 rows. I want the first and third row been selected by default. Could someone help me?

**Code I have tried:**

```
import UIKit

var variable = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

class ControllerClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return variable.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "intervalCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        cell.textLabel?.text = variable[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        // here is where selection is made
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: ,manipulate cell  on `indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == 2` at `cellForRowAt indexPath:`.

Comment: RAJAMONAH-S, I know how to find the indexPath but I don't know how to select that row

Comment: @Jack when you select row at time in table view only one row is select so you need to select two row that is not possible when you need to highlife row or differentiate row that is possible..

Comment: @SagarBhut it is possible, you only need to enable multipleSelection on your tableView, I will post an image showing the results of my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First select multipleSelection checkmark in storyboard, or by code `self.testTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`, then after tableview.reloadData put this 2 lines

```
    self.testTableView.selectRow(at:  IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    self.testTableView.selectRow(at:  IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

**Standard Code**

```
    self.testTableView.reloadData()
    self.testTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    //here is where selection is made
    self.testTableView.selectRow(at:  IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    self.testTableView.selectRow(at:  IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

**Specified this Example Code**

```
var variable = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

import UIKit

class ControllerClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return variable.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        cell.lblWordText?.text = variable[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.testTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.testTableView.reloadData()
        //here is where selection is made
        self.testTableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        self.testTableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    } 
    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        testTableView.dataSource = self 

    } 
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell. I have added your code here, but it didn't work (I've used only one of them)

Comment: @jack use this code below of your tableView.reloadData

Comment: @Jack please post all your viewController code, i will post your code with my code in the right place

Comment: wait just a moment please)

Comment: @Jack you don't have viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, only that?

Comment: oops,  I am sorry, I didn't highlight it)

Comment: I have it, check one more time please

Comment: Your viewController is a UITableViewController don't you?

Comment: Here is inheritance of my class UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource . It's view controller with table view in it

Comment: My class has no member testTableView

Comment: @Jack change testTableView by your tableView name

Comment: In that case it gives me, ambiguous reference to tableView

Comment: @Jack Please post all your current code again, post all your .swift code please

Comment: I have posted, please check one more time

Comment: @Jack replace all testTableView by tableView and try

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149311/discussion-between-reinier-melian-and-jack).